# meteor facebook error 666

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a project that is getting big, and I'm trying to login with meteor accounts-facebook package, but it shows error 666

I have already complete access to facebook info about the user trying to login but when Accounts.validateLoginAttempt() is called it returns an error with code 666

I've never seen that kind of error and there's nothing anywhere about that!

Here are my logs:

```
I20170509-09:14:53.403(-3)? ***options onCreateUser { profile: { name: 'Rafael Melo' } }
I20170509-09:14:53.420(-3)? ***user onCreateUser { createdAt: Tue May 09 2017 09:14:53 GMT-0300 (Hora Padrão da Bahia),
I20170509-09:14:53.421(-3)?   _id: 'S7a78CctLco7pddTQ',
I20170509-09:14:53.421(-3)?   services:
I20170509-09:14:53.421(-3)?    { facebook:
I20170509-09:14:53.422(-3)?       { accessToken: 'xxxxxx',
I20170509-09:14:53.422(-3)?         expiresAt: 1499436988665,
I20170509-09:14:53.423(-3)?         id: 'xxxx',
I20170509-09:14:53.423(-3)?         email: 'xxx@xxx.com',
I20170509-09:14:53.424(-3)?         name: 'Rafael Melo',
I20170509-09:14:53.424(-3)?         first_name: 'Rafael',
I20170509-09:14:53.440(-3)?         last_name: 'Melo',
I20170509-09:14:53.441(-3)?         link: 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxx/',
I20170509-09:14:53.448(-3)?         gender: 'male',
I20170509-09:14:53.454(-3)?         locale: 'en_US',
I20170509-09:14:53.456(-3)?         age_range: [Object] } } }
I20170509-09:14:53.840(-3)? ********Results? { statusCode: 200,
I20170509-09:14:53.841(-3)?   content: '{"first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Melo","picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\\/\\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\\/v\\/t1.0-1\\/p50x50\\/xxxxx.jpg?oh=xxxx&oe=xxxx"}},"email":"xxx\\u0040xxxxx.com","gender":"male","locale":"en_US","link":"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/app_scoped_user_id\\/xxx\\/","id":"xxx"}',
I20170509-09:14:53.842(-3)?   headers:
I20170509-09:14:53.842(-3)?    { 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
I20170509-09:14:53.843(-3)?      etag: '"3befwqdwqd7b4198656bb0c5cb"',
I20170509-09:14:53.844(-3)?      pragma: 'no-cache',
I20170509-09:14:53.845(-3)?      'cache-control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
I20170509-09:14:53.847(-3)?      'x-fb-rev': '303217',
I20170509-09:14:53.848(-3)?      'content-type': 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8',
I20170509-09:14:53.848(-3)?      'x-fb-trace-id': 'wqsdsa2mf9/',
I20170509-09:14:53.850(-3)?      'facebook-api-version': 'v2.7',
I20170509-09:14:53.862(-3)?      expires: 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT',
I20170509-09:14:53.862(-3)?      vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
I20170509-09:14:53.865(-3)?      'x-fb-debug': '2esdwqdasd/asdqdwqdqwd==',
I20170509-09:14:53.866(-3)?      date: 'Tue, 09 May 2017 12:14:52 GMT',
I20170509-09:14:53.867(-3)?      connection: 'close' },
I20170509-09:14:53.868(-3)?   data:
I20170509-09:14:53.868(-3)?    { first_name: 'Rafael',
I20170509-09:14:53.869(-3)?      last_name: 'Melo',
I20170509-09:14:53.879(-3)?      picture: { data: [Object] },
I20170509-09:14:53.880(-3)?      email: 'xxxx@xxxx.com',
I20170509-09:14:53.881(-3)?      gender: 'male',
I20170509-09:14:53.881(-3)?      locale: 'en_US',
I20170509-09:14:53.882(-3)?      link: 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxxxx/',
I20170509-09:14:53.883(-3)?      id: 'xxxxxxxxxxx' } }
I20170509-09:14:53.996(-3)? *****attempt { type: 'unknown',
I20170509-09:14:53.997(-3)?   allowed: false,
I20170509-09:14:53.998(-3)?   methodName: 'login',
I20170509-09:14:53.999(-3)?   methodArguments: [ { oauth: [Object] } ],
I20170509-09:14:53.999(-3)?   error:
I20170509-09:14:54.000(-3)?    { [Error: {"_id":"S7a78CctLco7pddTQ","services":{"facebook":{"accessToken":"23dscxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","expiresAt":1499436988665,"id":"xxxxxxxxxxx","email":"xxxx@xxxx.com","name":"Rafael Melo","first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Melo","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxxxx/","gender":"male","locale":"en_US","age_range":{"min":21}}},"emails":[{"address":"xxxx@xxxx.com","verified":true}],"profile":{"nome":"Rafael Melo","sexo":"Masculino"},"email":"xxxx@xxxx.com"} [666]]
I20170509-09:14:54.001(-3)?      error: 666,
I20170509-09:14:54.001(-3)?      reason: '{"_id":"S7a78CctLco7pddTQ","services":{"facebook":{"accessToken":"23dscxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","expiresAt":1499436988665,"id":"xxxxxxxxxxx","email":"xxxx@xxxx.com","name":"Rafael Melo","first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Melo","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxxxx/","gender":"male","locale":"en_US","age_range":{"min":21}}},"emails":[{"address":"xxxx@xxxx.com","verified":true}],"profile":{"nome":"Rafael Melo","sexo":"Masculino"},"email":"xxxx@xxxx.com"}',
I20170509-09:14:54.002(-3)?      details: undefined,
I20170509-09:14:54.003(-3)?      message: '{"_id":"S7a78CctLco7pddTQ","services":{"facebook":{"accessToken":"23dscxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","expiresAt":1499436988665,"id":"xxxxxxxxxxx","email":"xxxx@xxxx.com","name":"Rafael Melo","first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Melo","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxxxx/","gender":"male","locale":"en_US","age_range":{"min":21}}},"emails":[{"address":"xxxx@xxxx.com","verified":true}],"profile":{"nome":"Rafael Melo","sexo":"Masculino"},"email":"xxxx@xxxx.com"}',
I20170509-09:14:54.013(-3)?      errorType: 'Meteor.Error' },
```

I am using meteor accounts-facebook package.

EDIT:
onClick:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
            requestPermissions: ['public_profile', 'email']
        }, function(error) {
              if (error) {
                Session.set('errorMessage', error.reason || 'Unknown error');
                console.log("error", Session.get('errorMessage'));
              } else {
                console.log("Succeso FB!!")
            }
        });
```

hooks:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
        console.log("***options onCreateUser", options);
        console.log("***user onCreateUser", user)

        if (user.hasOwnProperty('services') && user.services.hasOwnProperty('facebook')  ) {
            let result = Meteor.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/' + user.services.facebook.id + '?access_token=' + user.services.facebook.accessToken + '&fields=first_name, last_name, picture, email, gender, locale, link');
            console.log("********Results?", result);

            let doc = {
                        _id: user._id,
                        services: user.services,
                        emails: [],
                        profile:{}
                      },
                fullNome = result.data.first_name + " " + result.data.last_name;

            doc.profile = {
                                index: '0',
                                nome: fullNome,
                                role: 'Usuário',
                                isValid: true,
                                isComplete: true,
                                imageId: '',
                            }
            doc.emails.push({ address:result.data.email, verified: true });

            console.log("***Doc no onCreateUser", doc);
            Meteor.users.simpleSchema().clean(doc);
            Schemas.User.validate(doc);
            check(doc, Meteor.users.simpleSchema())
            user = doc;

            return user;

        }
        else{
            return user;
        }
    });

    Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
        console.log("*****attempt", attempt);
    });

    Accounts.config({
        sendVerificationEmail: false,
        loginExpirationInDays: 10,
        forbidClientAccountCreation: false
    });
```

PACKAGES:

```
accounts-base                               1.2.14* A user account system
accounts-facebook                           1.1.0* Login service for Facebook accounts
accounts-password                           1.3.0* Password support for accounts
alanning:roles                              1.2.15* Authorization package for Meteor
aldeed:autoform                             5.8.1* Easily create forms with automatic insert and update, and aut...
aldeed:autoform-select2                     1.0.5* Custom select2 input type for AutoForm
aldeed:collection2                          2.10.0  Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the ...
aldeed:http-fix                             0.2.2+ Improves the core HTTP package
aldeed:moment-timezone                      0.4.0  Timezone support for moment.js, packaged for Meteor. See http...
aldeed:simple-schema                        1.5.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by co...
aldeed:template-extension                   4.0.0* Adds template features currently missing from the templating ...
ashutosh:email-att                          1.1.4  Send e-mails with attachments.
benjaminrh:event-hooks                      1.4.3  Provides hooks for various user-triggered events
benjaminrh:jquery-cookie                    0.1.0  A simple, lightweight jQuery plugin for reading, writing and ...
benjick:webcam                              0.0.2  WebcamJS for Meteor
bigdsk:inputmask                            3.1.63* JQuery InputMask for Meteor
cordova:cordova-plugin-android-permissions  0.10.0
cordova:cordova-plugin-camera               2.4.1
cordova:cordova-plugin-compat               1.1.0
cordova:cordova-plugin-crop-on-steroids     1.0.0
cordova:cordova-plugin-file                 4.3.2
cordova:cordova-plugin-file-transfer        1.6.2
dburles:collection-helpers                  1.0.4* Transform your collections with helpers that you define
dburles:google-maps                         1.1.5  Google Maps Javascript API v3
dschulz:jquery-qrcode                       1.0.2  jQuery.qrcode - a jQuery plugin for dynamically generating QR...
ecmascript                                  0.6.2* Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
email                                       1.1.17_1* Send email messages
es5-shim                                    4.6.15  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
fortawesome:fontawesome                     4.5.0* Font Awesome (official): 500+ scalable vector icons, customiz...
francocatena:status                         1.5.3  Displays the connection status between browser and server
gadicohen:phantomjs                         0.0.2  phantomjs installation script; wrapper for node phantomjs pac...
gibson:meteor-autonumeric                   0.0.2  Add jquery-autoNumeric library support
ground:db                                   0.3.15  Ground Meteor.Collections offline
hilios:jquery.countdown                     2.0.4  The Final Countdown plugin for jQuery
http                                        1.2.11* Make HTTP calls to remote servers
iron:router                                 1.0.13* Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jaywon:meteor-node-uuid                     1.0.1  Generate RFC compliant UUIDs using node-uuid.
jeremy:selectize                            0.12.1_5  Selectize is a hybrid of a textbox and <select> element us...
jesperwe:bootstrap-select                   1.7.4_4  Meteor wrapper for http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-...
jparker:crypto-md5                          0.1.1  MD5 algorithm for CryptoJS, standard secure algorithms
jquery                                      1.11.9* Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
kadira:debug                                3.2.2  Full Stack Debugging Solution for Meteor
kadira:dochead                              1.5.0  Isomorphic way to manipulate document.head for Meteor apps
kevohagan:sweetalert                        1.0.0  a beautiful replacement for javascript's alert()
lepozepo:accounting                         1.0.0  Accounting.js -  number, money and currency formatting - full...
lukemadera:social-share                     1.2.0  Cross platform (inc. Cordova) social sharing for facebook, tw...
markoshust:owl-carousel-2                   2.0.0-beta.3a  Owl Carousel 2
matb33:collection-hooks                     0.8.4  Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for insert/u...
matteodem:easy-search                       2.0.0  Easy-to-use search with Blaze Components (+ Elastic Search su...
meteor-base                                 1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteor-platform                             1.2.6  (Deprecated) Include a standard set of Meteor packages in you...
meteorhacks:aggregate                       1.3.0  Proper MongoDB aggregations support for Meteor
meteorhacks:async                           1.0.0  Set of async utilities to work with NPM modules and other asy...
meteorhacks:kadira                          2.30.0* Performance Monitoring for Meteor
meteorhacks:npm                             1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
meteorhacks:picker                          1.0.3  Server Side Router for Meteor
meteorhacks:ssr                             2.2.0  Server Side Rendering for Meteor with Blaze
meteorhacks:subs-manager                    1.6.4  Subscriptions Manager for Meteor
meteorhacks:zones                           1.6.0  Zone.Js integration for meteor
meteortoys:allthings                        3.0.0  Insanely Handy Development Tools
mizzao:autocomplete                         0.5.1  Client/server autocompletion designed for Meteor's collection...
mobile-experience                           1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mologie:reactive-selectize                  0.1.5  Keeps selectize.js's options in sync with a reactive data source
momentjs:moment                             2.14.4* Moment.js (official): parse, validate, manipulate, and displ...
mongo                                       1.1.15* Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
mrt:external-file-loader                    0.1.4  The External File Loader package helps easily load external j...
mystor:device-detection                     0.2.0  Client-Side Device Type Detection & Template Switching with O...
natestrauser:select2                        3.5.1* Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes.
nicolaslopezj:excel-export                  1.0.0  Export data to excel
numeral:numeral                             1.5.3_1  Numeral.js (official) - A library for formatting and manipu...
peerlibrary:fs                              0.1.7  fs node.js module with fiber-enabled synchronous functions
peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal                   1.0.4  Simple usage of bootstrap 3 modals.
percolate:momentum-iron-router              0.7.0  A momentum plugin for transitioning Iron Router pages
praxie:canvas-to-blob                       1.1.1  JavaScript Canvas to Blob is a function to convert canvas ele...
raix:handlebar-helpers                      0.2.5  Handlebar helpers
rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker                 1.5.1* Meteor packaging of eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker for Boots...
rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker-pt-br           1.5.1* Meteor packaging of Brazilian translation of eternicode/boots...
reactive-var                                1.0.10* Reactive variable
reywood:publish-composite                   1.4.2* Publish a set of related documents from multiple collections ...
rzymek:moment-locale-pt-br                  2.12.0* Moment.js pt-br locale. Companion package for rzymek:moment
sacha:spin                                  2.3.1  Simple spinner package for Meteor
sergeyt:typeahead                           0.11.1_9  Autocomplete package for meteor powered by twitter typeahe...
service-configuration                       1.0.11  Manage the configuration for third-party services
session                                     1.1.6* Session variable
sewdn:jquery-cropper                        1.0.0_1  Fengyuan Chen's terrific jQuery plugin for cropping/zooming...
shell-server                                0.2.1* Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command.
spiderable                                  1.0.13  Makes the application crawlable to web spiders
standard-minifier-css                       1.2.0_1* Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js                        1.2.0_1* Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by defa...
summernote:summernote                       0.8.1  summernote (official): jQuery+Bootstrap WYSIWYG editor with e...
tracker                                     1.1.2* Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker             4.17.37_1  Bootstrap 3 DateTime picker from @Eonasdan, packaged for ...
twbs:bootstrap                              3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsiv...
u2622:persistent-session                    0.4.4  Persistently store Session data on the client
usefulio:sync-methods                       0.2.0  Adds Meteor.syncMethods that lets you call an asynchonous ser...
vsivsi:file-collection                      1.3.6* Collections that efficiently store files using MongoDB GridFS...
williamledoux:bootstrap-toggle              2.2.1  Bootstrap Toggle Meteor component
xmlbuilder                                  2.5.14* An XML builder for node.js similar to java-xmlbuilder.
yogiben:autoform-modals                     0.3.8  Create, update and delete collections with modals
yogiben:helpers                             0.0.6  Meteor helpers that should come as standard
zimme:active-route                          2.0.4_1* Active route helpers
zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css                1.4.6  CSS to make Select2 fit in with Bootstrap 3
```

Comment: do you hook into `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt`? can you show the code you use?

Comment: Yes I do hook, I edited to show my code!

Comment: can you also provide which packages you use including their versions?

Comment: For sure! Edited to add packages!

Answer (score 0):

`Accounts.validateLoginAttempt` will drop the login attempt if faulsy value returned. More about that https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt

So in your case if you want to just show the results, you should do

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
    console.log("*****attempt", attempt);
    return true;
});
```

Second, there was some changes in Facebook API (we even had an internal server error because of that!), so I recommend to update to the latest accounts-facebook:

```
meteor update accounts-facebook
```

If update didn't change the version, update it manually via editing the `.meteor/versions` file

Comment: So, I added 'return true' to that part, but it didn't work. It keeps showing that:

`*****attempt { type: 'unknown',
allowed: false,`

even though I changed to return true

Comment: @RafaelMelo try also updating the package, and if that didn't work - try also commenting out the big part of code where you are replacing the `user` object, to trace down the error

Comment: I've deleted this part that you said and the error keeps happening and nothing changes, even the logs are equal. I also tried to update the package (it didn't work) but  with my meteor release it's recommended that I use that version, so I downgraded again...

Comment: @RafaelMelo i don't see `console.log("***Doc no onCreateUser", doc);` in the log you posted, so there's error between ***results and ***doc